# How can I make Gunicorn a daemon on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04, daemon, systemd, supervisord

I want to make Gunicorn a daemon.

I understand I can do this with `supervisor`/`systemd`, but for both of these, my Flask app needs to be in a `virtualenv`,which in my case it isn't.

It is essential that Gunicorn become a daemon. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its much simpler than you think , add `--daemon` to the end

---

Example:

```
web: gunicorn -w 3 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app --daemon
```

Example 2:

```
gunicorn --workers=2 'test:create_app()' --daemon
```

Example 3:

```
gunicorn --paste development.ini -b :8080 --chdir /path/to/project --daemon
```

Comment: @YagzicanDegirmenci  Thank you, but now how do I stop it?

Comment: `pkill gunicorn` stops all the running gunicorn daemons. But if you wanna stop a spesific daemon first grep that  `ps ax | grep gunicorn` and  `sudo lsof -t -i tcp:port_here | xargs kill -9` or you can use kill for ports also.